# Action Bar: menu icon looks different on devices with same screen density

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-support-library

Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong, the menu icon(green one) size is different also the density is the same and same resource is taken.

HTC One X:
DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=720, height=1280, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=213.0, ydpi=213.0}

Android 4.2.2

[image]

LG-p880:
DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=720, height=1280, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=309.9661, ydpi=309.6381}

Android 4.0.3

[image]

Comment: get the screen width and height programatically and see if both devices give same values.

Comment: Are you implementing it the same way as the magnifying glass? Because that icon looks exactly the same size on both.

Comment: 213 and 309 are clearly not the same. The icon on the HTC One X is smaller, since the actual screen size is bigger. This way, the physical size of the icon should be the same on both devices.

Comment: magnifying glass is a default searchview icon, i'm not adding it programatically. Image size is : 96*96px and it looks compressed in both cases but Action bar height is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I fixed by clipping the icon to be the appropriate size, see
http://stefan222devel.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/android-screen-densities-sizes.html

The search icon was 48x48 in hdpi while the rest 72x72.
Changing the latter to 48x48 makes them the same size on all versions :)

Action Bar icon's have smaller dimensions than the old menu icons!

Answer (score -2):

How very annoying! 4.2 appears to wholly display an menu item image true to its actual dimensions - while <4.2 chops a little off top and bottom. I guess the solution is to include your own search image from the SDK and accept smaller image icons on >4.2?